# Non-english characters are not displayed correctly in IntelliJ 14

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, intellij-idea, cyrillic, non-english

I have code :

```
    private static function askFromUser(cardId:uint):void {

        var s:String = "У клиента " + cardId + " произошло задвоение данных.";
        trace(s);
    }
```

It shows :

[trace] � ������� 436 ��������� ��������� ������.

What is the problem?

Comment: It's working fine for me using Flash CS5.5, CS6 and Flash CC ... What's your IDE ?

Comment: Intellij Idea 14.1.4

Comment: Honestly I don't use Intellij Idea. Try to verify your font and encoding settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IntelliJ probably does not have the correct File Encoding for that file.  The encoding IntelliJ is using should be displayed in the Status Bar near the lower right-hand corner of your IntelliJ window.  If you can't find it, [this page goes into great detail about changing file encodings in IntelliJ](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/).  If you don't know what encoding your file is in, [that can be difficult to determine](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/187174).

I copied and pasted your code into a UTF-8 encoded file in my own IntelliJ and it displayed fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with Intellij Idea. But i have tried embedding different fonts in flash project. There's a blog post detailing my experience with font embedding . May be that will help you. [font emebedding](http://www.logicmanialab.com/2011/03/font-embedding-in-flash-cs5.html)

Comment: The OP is speaking about a problem in the IDE itself ( the output panel ), not the flash project.